# how to use redis-rb with sinatra

Tags: sinatra, redis

I want to use redis with sinatra,and followed the [guide](http://redis-rb.keyvalue.org/v2.2.0/) like this

```
require "redis"

redis = Redis.new
```

then, I got the error

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- redis
```

maybe the lib of redis is not loading.

I git the redis-rb from [github](https://github.com/ezmobius/redis-rb) and copy the lib of redis into my sinatra app.

How can I install the redis-rb? I google something like that:

```
rake redis:install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you included redis in your "Gemfile"? It should be in your application root.

> I git the redis-rb from github and copy the lib of redis into my
>   sinatra app.

Why? It is more convenient to install redis via bundler. (Redis is available as a Ruby gem).

I'm sure you can find proper introductions to bunler via your favourite search engine, but let me show you an example "Gemfile" to use with bundler anyway:

```
source :rubygems

gem "bundler"
gem "sinatra"
gem "rack"
gem "redis"
```

When you run bundler, redis should be ready to go with your configuration.